# Managing Python Multiprocess processes with different memory ussage

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, task-queue

I use a simple RabbitMQ queue to distribute tasks to worker processes. Each worker process uses a pool of `multiprocessing` instances to work on multiple task at the same time to use the memory and the cpu as much as possible.

The problem is, that some of the task take much more RAM than the others, so that the worker process would crash if it starts more than one instance. But while the worker is working on the RAM intense task, I'd like it to work on other less RAM intense tasks to use the rest of the CPUs.

One idea would be to use multiple queues or topics but I am wondering what the recommended approach is. Can I catch out of memory errors before they crash the process?

What would be the right approach to solve this?

**[updated update]**

There whole system will consist of multiple multi core machines, but on each multi core machine there is only one worker program running, that creates as much multiprocessing instances as cores. The different machines should be independent of each other except that they get their tasks from the same queue.

Comment: Is this all done on one machine?

Comment: Yes, all on one machine.

Comment: How many cores does it have? You've got multiple worker processes each creating multiple processes inside of a `multiprocessing.Pool`. That sounds like a lot of total processes. Unless you've got as many cores as you have processes, you're only slowing yourself down (and wasting memory). Also, why have multiple worker processes if they're all consuming from the same queue and then sending the work off to yet another worker process that's part of a `Pool`? Why not have one worker process managing one `Pool`?

Comment: Hi Dano, thanks for your interest. On each machine there is one worker, that creates as much multiprocessing instances as cores.

Comment: I thought you said there was only one machine?

Comment: Hi, sorry I was not precise. There are multiple machines, but they should be independent of each other. For that reason I described originally how the system should work on one machine.

Comment: Thanks, that makes your architecture make much more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to catch and recover from OOM errors will be very difficult, if not impossible. You would need a thread or process to be running that constantly monitors memory usage, and when it detects it's too high, does...what exactly? Kills a process that's processing a task? tries to pause it (if that's possible; it may not be depending what yours tasks are doing). Even then, pausing it isn't going to release any memory. You'd have to release the memory and restart the task when its safe, which means you'd have to requeue it, decide when its safe, etc.

Instead of trying to detect and recover from the problem, I would recommend trying to avoid it altogether. Create two queues, and two pools. One queue/pool for high-memory tasks, and another queue/pool for low-memory tasks. The high-memory pool would only have a single process in it, so it would be limited to running one task concurrently, which saves your memory. The low-memory queue would have `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1` processes, allowing you to keep your CPUs saturated across the two pools.

One potential issue with this approach is that if you exhaust the high-memory queue while still having low-memory tasks pending, you'll be wasting one of your CPU. You could handle this consuming from the high-memory queue in a non-blocking way (or with a timeout), so that if the high-memory queue is empty when you're ready to consume a task, you can grab a low-memory task instead. Then when you're done processing it, check the high-memory queue again.

Something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

# hi_q and lo_q are placeholders for whatever library you're using to consume from RabbitMQ

def high_mem_consume():
    while True:
       task = hi_q.consume(timeout=2)
       if not task:
          lo_q.consume(timeout=2)
       if task:
           process_task(task)


def low_mem_consume():
    while True:
        task = lo_q.consume()  # Blocks forever
        process_task(task)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    hi_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    lo_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)
    hi_pool.apply_async(high_mem_consume)
    lo_pool.apply_async(lo_mem_consume)
```